# Is there a difference between a borrowed integer and a copy?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I know that a `String` mainly consists of a pointer that contains the address to its allocated place in the heap memory. Rust prohibits any copies of `String`s to avoid double free errors, so it introduced borrowing, where the code basically only copies the pointer value without copying the value in the heap.

However, integer types are stored in the stack and hence do not have a pointer. Yet it is still possible to create a reference to an integer:

```
let i: i64 = 42;
let j = &i;
```

Since an integer contains no reference to the heap, isn't a borrowed integer simply a regular copy of it? E.g. is there any difference between `j = i` and `j = &i`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the case if the reference were *mutable*:

```
let mut i: u64 = 42;
let j = &mut i;

*j = 5;
println!("{}", i);
```

```
5
```

It should be obvious from this demonstration that `j` is not simply a copy. It does reference and therefore modify the original `i`.

> Integer types are stored in the stack and hence do not have a pointer.

Not sure where you got that idea from. If it exists in memory, then it has an address within that memory, and therefore you can have a pointer (or reference) that points to it. The properties of a `u64` do not change depending on where it is.

The comparison to strings may be tripping you up:

```
let s = String::from("hello world");
let s_ref: &String = &s;
let str_ref: &str = s.as_str();
```

If you have a `String` variable `s`, and take a reference to it, `s_ref`, it does *not* point directly to the heap, it points to the variable `s` on the stack. There is a slice-type `str` that represents a region of utf8-encoded bytes, which a `String` holds on the heap. You can get a reference to that region of memory directly on the heap by getting it via `.as_str()`/`.as_ref()` or by converting the `&String` into a `&str` via deref coercion.

But in the case of `u64` vs `&u64`, there isn't much of a *practical* difference between the two except the latter incurs an extra level of indirection in the generated code and you may have to worry about lifetime constraints. Because of that, its usually better to use *copies* of integer types if given the choice. You'd still see references to integers though if using them through some generic interface.

Comment: It can exist in _register_ and not have an address but the compiler takes care not to store things there if their address is taken.

Comment: I'm well aware and I don't think that aids in the explanation, especially when that is a compiler/hardware detail and not important to understanding Rust's semantics.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to note.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a difference between the two. The fact that an integer lives in the heap, or in the stack, doesn't change the fact that it's somewhere in the memory, so it has an address. A pointer being just that address, even integers can have pointers to. And, indeed, if you try using a pointer to an integer as an integer, you'll have a problem, because of type mismatch.

The difference between a `String` and a number type such as `i64` is that `i64: Copy`, which means that you can turn a `&i64` into a `i64` just by "copying" the values (as opposed to calling a dedicated function that knows how to appropriately clone stuff, such as `String::clone`, which comes from `Clone::clone`). This means that Rust will allow implicit copying of an integer, so, from this perspective, a pointer to an integer is as permissive as an integer in itself.